# Extract service call to a helper?

Tags: java, exception, api-design

I have two APIs in serviceA that call the same other API of serviceB. The only difference is that the two APIs invoke the serviceB API with different request parameters. As a result, the two APIs in serviceA have common exceptions to handle but also unique ones. Below is a simple code example

```
public class ServiceB {
    public Response someAPI(Request request) {
        //some common business logic
        if (request.param1 != null) {
            //some logic that only applies if param1 is present
            if (someUniqueError) {
                throw new someUniqueException();
            }
        }
        if (errorCondition1) {
            throw new Exception1();
        } else if (errorCondition2) {
            throw new Exception2();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
public class ServiceA {
    public void op1(Param1 param1, Param2 param2) {
        ...
        Request request;
        request.setParam1(param1);
        request.setParam2(param2);
        Response response;
        try{
            response = ServiceBClient.someAPI(request);
        } catch (SomeUniqueException e) {
            //some error handling
        } catch (Exception1 e) {
            //some error handling
        } catch (Exception2 e) {
            //some error handling
        }
        ...
    }
    public void op2(Param2 param2) {
        ...
        Request request;
        request.setParam2(param2);
        Response response;
        try{
            response = ServiceBClient.someAPI(request);
        } catch (Exception1 e) {
            //some error handling
        } catch (Exception2 e) {
            //some error handling
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

My question is, should I extract service call to `someAPI` to a helper function so that I don't have duplicate exception handling logic or should each API be responsible for their own error handling? What is a good practice here?

helper that I am thinking of

```
private Response helper(Request request) {
    Response response;
    try{
        response = ServiceBClient.someAPI(request);
    } catch (SomeUniqueException e) {
        //some error handling
    } catch (Exception1 e) {
        //some error handling
    } catch (Exception2 e) {
        //some error handling
    }
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With some certainity, you probably should extract at least a part of your code to some sort of a `sendRequest` method.
The disclaimer being, that to be completely sure, one would have to understand the business requirements of your app,

Now you just have to decide if you want to handle `UniqueException` only in `op1`. If so, you should leave the `try/catch` for this particular exception there. Otherwise move it to the helper, as you did.

Depending on the complexity of your system, and possibility of also having `op3`, `op4`, etc., you might want to think of creating a `RequestBuilder`, too.